# Using the Scanner to read the user's input, is there a way to tell what kind of data he has just typed in? (char, int,String)

Tags: java

In this exercise i'm being asked to create 3 functions, which are the same but are meant for different types of data:

**String**

```
    static String concatenamento(String a, String b, String c) {

    String d = a + b + c;

    return d;
}
```

**Int**

```
    static int sommainteri(int a, int b, int c) {

    int d = a + b + c;

    return d;
}
```

**Double**

```
    static double sommadouble(double a, double b, double c) {

    double d = a + b + c;

    return d;
}
```

I'm being asked to ask the user's for input continuously, and given it's inputs the program must, (as soon as 3 inputs are given with the same data type), choose a function and execute it. End of the program.

I'm not sure this is clear, so i'll try to explain it better. Let's say that the user has just inserted, in a row, three integers (f.ex. 3, 4 and 9), the program must understand to use the function made for integers.

I have no idea how to do it. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `10.53` : is this a double(`10.53`), a string (`"10.53"`) or an int (`10` followed by `"."` followed by `53`)?

Comment: As far as i know, that's a double for me. Your point is right though, it could be interpreted differently. I'm confused now!

Comment: @FilipeMadureira Don't worry the Scanner is robust enough to determine that is a double if you use `hasNextDouble()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout Scanner's `hasNextInt()` `hasNextDouble()`

Simple Example Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    if(s.hasNextInt()) {
        int x = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Is an Int: " + x);
    } else if(s.hasNextDouble()) {
        double x = s.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Is a Double:" + x);
    } else {
        String x = s.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Is A String: "  + x );
    }
}
```

Comment: Woah, let me understand, hasNextInt() returns true if the next set of data can be read as Int? That's perfect for my problem! Is there a way to use this approach for Strings too?

Comment: One caveat: try for double first. You need to try double first because the beginning of double can be interpreted as int.

Comment: @Arkadiy That is incorrect. An Int can be interpreted as a Double but not the other way around. Easily proved by switching the statements and using 1, 2.5, 3 as inputs...

Comment: @FilipeMadureira The String would be the default case (you may first check for the other types if you don't want to treat them as Strings)